# Best practice to unit test a ViewModel in ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I am creating unit tests for my code, I have a question about one of them:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Delete_Id()
    {
        // Arrange
        Mock.Arrange(() => journalRepository.GetJournalById(1)).Returns(new Journal
        {
            Id = 1,
            Description = "TestDesc",
            FileName = "TestFilename.pdf",
            Title = "Tester",
            UserId = 1,
            ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now
        });

        // Act
        PublisherController controller = new PublisherController(journalRepository, membershipRepository);
        ViewResult result = controller.Delete(1) as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        JournalViewModel model = result.Model as JournalViewModel;
        Assert.AreEqual(model.Description, "TestDesc");
    }
```

As you can see int he code above, I created a Journal object with several properties and sent it to my PublisherController for testing. However in the Assert part of the code, I am only testing one of the properties.

My question is: is it enough to test one of the properties, or should I test them all? And if I should test them all, is it possible to automate it, instead of test each propertiy of the returned object?

What is the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, testing all available properties will result into a more reliable test result. By doing so, you will be able to determine bugs where the controller changed a property value even though it wasn't meant to do so.

You'd just have to use `Assert` for each property to test (I'm not aware of anyway to automate this ATM).

Take note that unit testing is meant to be thorough. If you are not constrained by time then better make sure everything runs smoothly by testing everything as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice in this case would be primarily opinion based.

However, if you want to compare the entire object you could have the object as a variable and then compare them.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Delete_Id() {
    // Arrange
    var expected = new Journal {
        Id = 1,
        Description = "TestDesc",
        FileName = "TestFilename.pdf",
        Title = "Tester",
        UserId = 1,
        ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now
    };
    Mock.Arrange(() => journalRepository.GetJournalById(1)).Returns(expected);

    var controller = new PublisherController(journalRepository, membershipRepository);

    // Act
    var result = controller.Delete(1) as ViewResult;
    var model = result.Model as JournalViewModel;

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, model);
}
```